# .lhs with sublime text 2

Tags: haskell, sublimetext2

The built in language on sublime text for (.lhs) literate Haskell files does nothing. There is a question that already exists on stack overflow, but I couldn't get it to work. Does anyone what I should add to the language file to treat lines of code that do not have a ">" as a comment and everything else as it would a normal Haskell file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In SublimeText2, go in menu `Preferences`>`Browse Packages...`, then navigate to `Haskell` folder. To be able to build with Sublime's auto build system, in this folder you should have a file named `Literate Haskell.sublime-build`.

You can start by copying `Haskell.sublime-build` already present and renaming it. Now you have to update the command.

Now, because [Haskell's Wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Literate_programming) suggests `ghc -optL -q` to compile Literate Haskell, the sublime-build file would become:

```
{
    "cmd": ["ghc", "-optL -q", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.haskell"
}
```

P.S. - You may have to restart SublimeText
P.S. - I didn't test it.

Comment: Copying the contents from the haskell language file will make the file look just as it would for a normal haskell file, and still try and highlight the lines that do not have a ">" infront of them.

Comment: The main idea was to mimic that file, but add some `GHC` flags to tell it to handle Literate style